# Remove meta box for specific page

Tags: metabox, conditional-tags, page-attributes

I'm trying to conditionally remove the 'Page Attributes' meta box for a specific page (or multiple specific pages). For example:

```
function remove_meta_boxes() {
  if (is_page('contact')) {
    remove_meta_box('pageparentdiv', 'page', 'side');
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_meta_boxes' );
```

I'm able to remove the Page Attributes meta box for all pages without the conditional statement, so that part is working, but adding the `is_page()` condition seems to cause the `remove_meta_box()` code not to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `is_page()` conditional relies on the `global $wp_query` WP_Query object which isn't set on the edit post page. We have some other options though...

If we know the page ID we can test against $_GET:

```
/**
 * Remove metaboxes
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function wpse343020_remove_meta_boxes() {

    if( isset( $_GET, $_GET['post'] ) && 123 == $_GET['post'] ) {
        remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv', 'page', 'side' );
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse343020_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

If you really need to test against the page title or page slug you can hook in later whenever the `global $post` WP_Post object is available:

```
/**
 * Remove metaboxes
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function wpse343020_remove_meta_boxes() {

    global $post;

    if( ! empty( $post ) && 'contact' == $post->post_name ) {
        remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv', 'page', 'side' );
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse343020_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions! I was able to get the first one to work, using the page ID, but not the second one, using the slug. And unfortunately I _do_ need to use the slug because sometimes I'm dealing with slightly different instances of the database depending on the environment and so the page IDs aren't always the same. Any idea why using the slug didn't work?

Comment: Maybe you can print the `$post` and `$_REQUEST` to see if the slug exists in either of those: `printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $post, 1 ) ); die( 'end' );`